# loop through android hashmap array

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I've got my php code:

```
<?php

require('conn.php');

$json = array();
$newquery = "SELECT * FROM absent";
$newresult = mysqli_query($conn, $newquery);

$jsonData = array();
while ($array = mysqli_fetch_array($newresult)) {
array_push($jsonData,array(
"username"=>$array['username'],
"date"=>$array['date']  
    ));
}
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$jsonData), true);


mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

and it returned :

{"result":[{"username":"verarmond","date":"2016-11-17"},{"username":"henk","date":"2016-11-15"}]}

How can i get only usernames and only dates in android ??

Thanks and regard.

Comment: Then what is problem use `iOS` and `Android` as key to get 100,101 from HashMap . or looking for something else?

Comment: `alist` is what? Print your values where? Why are you parsing JSON and doing nothing with it?

Comment: check my answer

Comment: alist is ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>alist = new ArrayList<>(); honestly i dont understand JSON so i looked for examples.. and now i asked for help.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the entries from a map:

```
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
for ( 
        Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String Value = entry.getValue();
        values.add(Value); //this will add all the values in the hashmap into `values` arraylist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HashMap is a data structure based on (key, value) pairs.
So, when you do this:

```
map.put("iOS", "100");
map.put("Android", "101");
```

You put the value "100" at "iOS" key, and value "101" at "Android" key.
If you want to access this values, you simply use the "map" object and get the value by the key, like this:

```
String val1 = map.get("iOS"); //this returns "100"
String val2 = map.get("Android"); // this returns "101"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy, you can do it by translating your JSON result to a JSON object with:

```
JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Then take your JSON array named `result`:

```
JSONArray jsonResultArray =  new JSONArray(jsonResult.getJSONArray("result"));
```

Now you can iterate through your JSON Array to get the required elements:

```
for(JSONObject jsonObject:jsonResultArray) {
    Log.d("TAG", "User: " + jsonObject.getString("username"));
    Log.d("TAG", "Date: " + jsonObject.getString("date"));
}
```

You should know that every `{` means a JSONObject and the `[` means a JSONArray, wit that you should have enough to go.

I wrote the code on the fly and can't check it now, maybe there are some typo or error.